# Is there some sort of wildcard when fetching data?

Tags: javascript, html, json, fetch-api

I want to display the name of the currency of different countries.
To do this I use an API and fetch the json in my JS file.

[image: this is the json response file I get calling Brazil]

[image: This is the json response file I get calling USA]

The problem is the different names. In this case "BRL" oder "USD" to enter the names of the currencies.

[image: my code to call the name of brazils currency]

In this case I used "BRL", but I want to be able to enter every different countries currency element. I would think that I would need some sort of wildcard.

Maybe some of you can help me on how to handle this problem.

Comment: **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Please [edit] your question to include the text.

Comment: All you need is bracket notation to retrieve the object by its key, using an arbitrary string.

Comment: `Object.entries(data[0].currencies)`

Answer (score 0):

I actually found out that there is an older version of the API in which the currency is display a lot simplier. That way I can access the currencies of each country easier.

[In the older version the json for USA´s currency for example would look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHoWP.png)

That way I dont actually need to enter the different kinds of currencies first, when fetching the data.

Comment: Without more details (example JSON returned in the alternate API?) your answer is more of a comment.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

you can do it more simple way

```
document.querySelector("#currency").innerHTML = 
                          Object.values(data[0].currencies)[0].name;
```

or maybe this if you want to show several properties

```
function displayCountry(data) {
  data.forEach((item) => {
    Object.keys(item.currencies).forEach((key) => {
      document.querySelector("#currency").innerHTML = item.currencies[key].name;
    });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a solution like yours.

Answer (score -2):

If you are calling the API with a currency abbreviation like "USD" and "BRL", then you can put those into an array like this:

```js
const arrayOfCurrencies = ["USD", "BRL", ...];
```

When you are displaying them to the DOM, you can use those values as dynamic properties of the response like so:

```js
for(let abbr of arrayOfCurrencies) {
  document.querySelector("#currency").innerHTML = data[0].currencies?.[abbr]?.name ?? fallbackString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would definetly be a possibility, but surely a lot of work, to filter out the different currencies that exist and put them in an array.

Comment: I was basing that assumption on the fact that your API response example images were of one currency at a time, so I thought that you would be making those requests with an array of your own currency abbreviations. If that isn't the case, perhaps I should have left a comment asking for clarification.